# Generic jenkins job for multiple projects

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, svn, maven-3

I have **multiple independent** projects ( ***Java - Maven*** ) in this SVN repo :

```
        |-- exemple.com/svn/java/apps/
        |
        |   |-- Application_1
        |   |   |-- branches
        |   |   |-- tag
        |   |   |-- trunk
        |
        |   |-- Application_2
        |   |   |-- branches
        |   |   |-- tag
        |   |   |-- trunk
```

Can I create a generic Jenkins maven build job with this SVN repository URL ***exemple.com/svn/java/apps/*** and put as parameter the ***project name*** and ***branche name*** ?

Something like this **${Project_Name}** and **${Branch_name}**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but that would mix up the job histories, someone trying to check it would be confused by the alternating histories.

It's more work, but it would probably be better, in my opinion, if you use a [Jenkins Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) or the [Jenkins Job DSL (a job generator)](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin).